# Creating a LARGE matrix of values using a PIVOT function

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In this example, I have a large number of IDs (1.6m+), with a 0/1 value in each of n rules.

## Example Table:

```
| ID      | Rule 1 | Rule 2 | Rule 3 | Rule 4 |.....
| :-----: | :----: | :----: | :----: | :----: |
| 12721   | 1      | 1      | 0      | 1      |  
| 12722   | 1      | 1      | 1      | 1      | 
| 12723   | 0      | 1      | 0      | 0      |
| 12724   | 0      | 1      | 0      | 0      |
| 12725   | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
| 12726   | 1      | 1      | 0      | 1      |
| 12727   | 0      | 1      | 1      | 1      |
.......
```

I'm trying to create a 'relationship matrix' (I don't know the proper name for it) that how often two columns share the same value.

## Desired result:

```
| ID      | Rule 1 | Rule 2 | Rule 3 | Rule 4 |.....
| :-----: | :----: | :----: | :----: | :----: |
| Rule 1  | -      | 3      | 1      | 3      |
| Rule 2  | 3      | -      | 2      | 4      |
| Rule 3  | 1      | 2      | -      | 2      |
| Rule 4  | 3      | 4      | 2      | -      |
.....
```

I understand that I'll need to use some sort of PIVOT function, but I don't know the exact approach I need to even start.

I already have;

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(Rule_1), SUM(Rule_2), SUM(Rule_3), SUM(Rule_4)...
FROM TABLE
```

for another requirement of the piece I'm working on

Comment: The desired results you present doesn't correspond strictly to the idea of "same value", it looks like you are counting how many time both columns have 1, because lines 12723 and 12724 have (rule 1, rule 3) both at 0 + line 12722 has both (rule 1, rule 3) to 1, so the # of times rule 1 and rule 3 have the same value should be 3, not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequence of UNPIVOT, JOIN the UNPIVOT-ed data with itself on the conditions, COUNT by grouping on the 2 columns contains the rules, and then PIVOT to get the final result:
(I tested in ORACLE but it's ANSI SQL so it should work as is in SQLServer, I just removed the "from dual")

```
WITH data(id, r1, r2, r3, r4) AS (
    SELECT 12721, 1, 1, 0, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12722, 1, 1, 1, 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 12723, 0, 1, 0, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12724, 0, 1, 0, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12725, 0, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12726, 1, 1, 0, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12727, 0, 1, 1, 1 
),
udata AS (
    SELECT * FROM data
    UNPIVOT (
        val for col in (r1, r2, r3, r4)
    )
),
sdata AS (
    SELECT s1.id, s1.col as col1, s2.col as col2, s1.val
    FROM udata s1
    JOIN udata s2 ON s1.id = s2.id AND s1.val = s2.val AND s1.col <> s2.col AND s1.val = 1
),
cdata AS (
    SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(*) AS c 
    FROM sdata
    GROUP BY col1, col2

)
SELECT * FROM cdata
PIVOT (
    MAX(c) FOR col2 IN ('R1' as r1, 'R2' as r2, 'R3' as r3, 'R4' as r4)
)
ORDER by col1
;


R1      3   1   3
R2  3       2   4
R3  1   2       2
R4  3   4   2
```

Comment: Thanks! With a little fiddling this worked perfectly! No to understand exactly how it works..... XD